# X Editable Select values loaded from MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, x-editable

I am having issue in loading the select options from server using x editable plugin for in place edit.Data in select option is shown as [object object] instead of actual options. Here is my code:

```
<a href="#" id ="status" data-name="group" data-type="select" data-source='@Url.Action("ProductGroups")' data-value="1" class="editable-click" title="Group">Operator</a>
```

ProductGroups action returns JSON response in following format **[{"value":1,"text":"Default"}]** from controller. In controller i am doing this.

```
public JsonResult  ProductGroups()
{
     var list = new List<xEditableItem>();
      foreach (var item in db.ProductGroups.ToList<ProductGroup>().OrderBy(r=> r.Name))
      {
         list.Add(new xEditableItem() { value = item.ID, text = item.Name });
      }
      return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public class xEditableItem { public int value {get;set;} public string text {get;set;} }
```

I event try passing select options manually like this but the result is the same [object object] in select list.

```
<a href="#" id ="status" data-name="group" data-type="select" data-source='[{"value":1,"text":"Default"}]' data-value="1" class="editable-click" title="Group">Operator</a>
```

Comment: data-source should be an array, try this: `data-source='[{value:1,text:'Default'}]'` << use singlequotes for text not for "variable".

Answer (score 1):

**Problem might be the single quote:**
**From**

```
data-source='@Url.Action("ProductGroups")'
```

**To**

```
data-source="@Url.Action("ProductGroups")"
```

And you can test passing select options manually:
**From**

```
data-source='[{"value":1,"text":"Default"}]'
```

**To**

```
data-source="[{"value":1,"text":"Default"}]"
```